# How do I append both an element and text to a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, text, append

I'm using jQuery and trying to append both an element and some text to an existing div element.  However, when I try this

```
$('<img src="/img.png" />').appendTo(gMenuItemInnerDiv);
$(gMenuItemInnerDiv).text(name);
```

The img element from the first line is wiped out.  How can I get both things into my div?

Comment: @JamesMaa you can't insert html using `text()`

Comment: What are expected results? If you switch the order, the text would be first. If you want text last ...use append()

Comment: `text()` replaces all contents of the element with what you give it, including the img you just appended.  Why not append your text?

Comment: @charlietfl, I want to HTML escape the text, so you're sayihng I would do $(myText).appendTo(gMenuItemInnerDiv) ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by html escape the text. Did you try switching the order you call the 2 methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var gMenuItemInnerDiv = $('#something');
var name = "<b>Yay</b>";

$('<img src="/img.png" />').appendTo(gMenuItemInnerDiv);
gMenuItemInnerDiv.append( document.createTextNode(name) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
$('<img src="/img.png" />').appendTo(gMenuItemInnerDiv);
$('<span>' + name +'</span>').appendTo(gMenuItemInnerDiv);
```

:)

Comment: You're changing the conditions of my question.  There is no "span" element around my text, nor do I want there to be.