# Jquery analogue for html innerHTML + =

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to put value from button to text place.I do this .
`text($(button).val());`
But it just replaces the text I need when I need just to `+` this value.Like value is `5` then then again `+ 5` so it will be `55`.

Comment: look at [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: did u mean 5+5 = 55? or 5+5 = 10 ? are you looking to append values or do some methamatical calclations ?

Comment: You can use a created text node in conjunction with append() to perform a text append, if you don't want it to possibly be rendered as html.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577548/how-do-i-append-both-an-element-and-text-to-a-div-in-jquery/44577694#44577694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.text($(button).val());
```

You may use:

[.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function): where function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

An example:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#txt').text(function(idx, txt) {
        return txt + val;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="txt"></p>
<button id="btn" value="5">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to get the contents of a button and then add to it, you need to do the following. Let's say the button is as follows:

```
<button id="someButton">5</button>
```

You want to add 5 to it so the button says 10.

```
var buttonText = parseInt($("#someButton").text()) + 5; //results in 10
$("#someButton").text(buttonText);
```

As you can see, I used `parseInt` to ensure the number was seen an integer so you could perform addition on it.

Comment: Sorry, for the mistake.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```js
function addText () {
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML += $('#buttonID').val();
}
```

Try this. This `+=` to the innerHTML as opposed to re-assigning. It is a JavaScript/jQuery hybrid, which I hope is okay, but there is also this pure jQuery method that uses the .append() method that @Patrick Evans mentioned.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#paragraph').append($('#buttonID').val());
});
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: The OP was looking for the jQuery way of doing  it.

Comment: Actually, the OP never specified whether he wanted jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: I don't think this comment thread is enriching the discussion. I realize that I was incorrect, and hope you are satisfied at this point in time. I have edited my answer to include pure jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to just append values:

```
<button class="display-value">5</button>

<button id="plus">+</button>
```

Now you can do this in jQuery:

```
$('#plus').on('click' , () => {
    let val = $('.display-value').text();
    $('.display-value').text((val + val));
    return false;
});
```

If you're looking to perform a mathematical operation then, you will have to use `parseInt`.

```
$('#plus').on('click' , () => {
     let val = parseInt($('.display-value').text());
     $('.display-value').text((val + val));
     return false;
});
```